# Split the Parameters if QUERY_STRING exceeds specified length using AJAX and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am working in rails application.I am using AJAX to send form data.Here problem is i couldn't send huge query string in while post data.Getting error Invalid request: HTTP element QUERY_STRING is longer than the (1024 * 10) allowed length.Is it possible to split the data based on length.If length exceeds maximum limits,it has to split the value and run one more time.How to implement this.Below the ajax call i am using.Parameter value is huge.

```
                $.ajax({
                    url: "get_object",
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        parameter: parameter_name,
                        mac: macAdd,
                        protocol: protocol,
                        serialnumber: serialnumber,
                        oid: oid
                    },



                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        NProgress.done();
                            console.log("Call Success");


                    },

                    statusCode: {
                        404: function () {
                            console.log("Call failed");
                        }
                    }
                });


            })();
```

Comment: Are you sure this is doing a `POST` request? I have a suspicion that this error is triggered because you are actually doing a `GET` where the params in `data` are encoded in the URL and the URL length is limited. Can you try using `method: 'POST'` instead of `type: 'POST'` as I think that's the proper way to indicate the type of request with jQuery as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks.But still i am getting same error HTTP element QUERY_STRING is longer than the (1024 * 10) allowed length.

Comment: method: 'Post' is not working .Getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: Getting a different error confirms my suspicion that this was the problem because it happens on a different step. Previously it failed during parsing of the request and now it happens during routing. Don't know how to solve that in your case as I'm missing details about your server. Also this type of request should really be a `GET` and you should probably rethink your idea so that you don't need to send such a long query string. In case sending this amount of params is a hard requirement you'd need to abuse `POST` and you'd need to reflect this in your routing somehow.

Comment: Ok thanks.i will check.